# Print the name of the column with no missing value

Tags: r

I have several columns per ID. Each ID can only be present in one column, the other columns being NA.

```
ID<-1:5
var1<-c(1,NA,NA,1,NA)
var2<-c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
var3<-c(NA,NA,1,NA,1)
data<-data.frame(ID,var1,var2,var3)
print(data)

  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1    1 <NA> <NA>
2  2 <NA>    1 <NA>
3  3 <NA> <NA>    1
4  4    1 <NA> <NA>
5  5 <NA> <NA>    1
```

I want to create a last column in which the name of the column in which each ID is present will be printed, like this:

```
  ID var1 var2 var3  All
1  1    1 <NA> <NA> var1
2  2 <NA>    1 <NA> var2
3  3 <NA> <NA>    1 var3
4  4    1 <NA> <NA> var1
5  5 <NA> <NA>    1 var3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max.col` :

```
data$All <- names(data)[-1][max.col(!is.na(data[-1]))]
data

#  ID var1 var2 var3  All
#1  1    1   NA   NA var1
#2  2   NA    1   NA var2
#3  3   NA   NA    1 var3
#4  4    1   NA   NA var1
#5  5   NA   NA    1 var3
```

`-1` ignores `ID` column from the calculation.